# Avahi rejects cups print jobs after system upgrade

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, cups, brother-printer, avahi

I recently upgraded my system from RHEL 6.5 to 7.2. A previously working network printer stopped working. The printer is configured as before with the same driver and options. Trying to print a simple PDF document, all I can see in terms of error is in `/var/log/messages` (`/var/logs/cups/error_log` does not have an error):

> Apr 28 09:53:49 machineName dbus[942]: [system] Rejected send message,
> 10 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.151" (uid=70
> pid=12531 comm="avahi-daemon: starting up ") interface="(unset)"
> member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0"
> destination=":1.87" (uid=500 pid=23243 comm="evince /home/user/xxxx")
>
> Apr 28 09:53:49 machineName dbus[942]: [system] Rejected send message,
> 10 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.151" (uid=70
> pid=12531 comm="avahi-daemon: starting up ") interface="(unset)"
> member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0"
> destination=":1.87" (uid=500 pid=23243 comm="evince /home/user/xxxxx")
>
> Apr 28 09:53:49 machineName dbus-daemon: dbus[942]: [system] Rejected
> send message, 10 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.151"
> (uid=70 pid=12531 comm="avahi-daemon: starting up ")
> interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)"
> requested_reply="0" destination=":1.87" (uid=500 pid=23243
> comm="evince /home/user/xxxxx")

The printer is connected via USB to a print server in the local network. Other machines can reach the printer and successfully print. Is this a network issue with avahi? Do I need to create a service file? Anything else to look into?

Comment: Have you tried unplugging it and restarting the printer? see if then it may work with it? what are the other computers running the same version of RHEL or something else?

Comment: Well, the printer runs fine as network printer for other computers. I tried using it as network printer on the RHEL machine in question, as local USB printer, with different drivers, with different settings, after re-installing avahi and dbus, ... No success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(After some more hours of debugging) The error is caused by SELinux policies.

`sudo getenforce` shows `enforced`, i.e., SELinux is on. 
After turning it off via `sudo setenforce 0` it is possible to print. I found some [documentation by Brother](http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/faq_prn.html?c=us_ot&lang=en&comple=on&redirect=on#30) that has some guidance on how to keep SELinux enabled and still being able to print. It involves adding some policies and re-applying them to the installed driver files.